# Issue with calabash, simulator not coming up on mac

Tags: ios, cucumber, rubymotion, calabash

```
 - 

 Run {"SDK_VERSION"="6.1", "OS"="ios6", "DEVICE"="iphone",   
 "DEVICE_TARGET"="device_family=iphone",   
 "BUNDLE_ID"="com.mckinsey.internal.Directory_dev",   
 "APP_BUNDLE_PATH"="/Users/ashish/Workspace/office/ks/firm_directory/build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Directory.app"}
 cucumber Waiting at most 30 seconds for simulator (CONNECT_TIMEOUT)   
 Retrying at most 2 times (MAX_CONNECT_RETRY) (1.) Start Simulator
    6.1, iphone, for /Users/ashish/Workspace/office/ks/firm_directory/build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Directory.app
 Using installed ios-sim at /usr/local/bin/ios-sim sh: line 1:  2683   
 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /usr/local/bin/ios-sim "launch"   
 "/Users/ashish/Workspace/office/ks/firm_directory/build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Directory.app"

 "--sdk" "6.1" "--family" "iphone" "--exit" 2&1 Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Ping   
 http://localhost:37265/... Ping http://localhost:37265/... Timed   
 out...



 class or module required for rescue clause (TypeError)
 /Users/ashish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.136/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:225:in
 `rescue in ensure_connectivity'
 /Users/ashish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.136/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:174:in
 `ensure_connectivity'
 /Users/ashish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.136/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:25:in
 `relaunch'
 /Users/ashish/Workspace/office/ks/firm_directory/features/support/launch.rb:78:in
 `relaunch'
 /Users/ashish/Workspace/office/ks/firm_directory/features/support/launch.rb:156:in
 `AfterConfiguration' Using installed ios-sim at /usr/local/bin/ios-sim
```

I am trying to run feature tests but the simulator does not show up, running with NO_LAUNCH=1 does run the features.

I am running  Ruby 2.1.1 on Mavericks

Please help out getting this fixed ..

Answer (score 0):

`NO_LAUNCH=1` means that you must start the app on the simulator or device yourself.

And now that I look back on this:

```
calabash-cucumber-0.9.136
```

Your gem is very out of date - the latest version is 0.9.169.

```
$ gem install calabash-cucumber
```

and follow the instructions here to update your calabash.framework:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B1-Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version

and be sure to read this:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/A0-Xcode-51-Support